# How to get all the params of a POST request with Compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

According to the [Compojure documentation on routes](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Routes-In-Detail), I can easily get individual parameters like this:

```
(POST "/my-app" [param1 param2]
  (str "<h1>Hello " param1 " and " param2 "</h1>"))
```

How do I get ***all*** parameters, not just individual parameters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

compojure handlers receive the entire request map as their argument, so handler has also an access to all of the parameters. For example, to see entire request:

```
(POST "/" request
    (str request))
```

or, to extract all form parameters:

```
(POST "/" request
    (str (:form-params request)))
```

The syntax used in the question is a compojure-specific [destructuring syntax](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax), which allows extracting individual parameters from the request. This is similar to clojure's usual destructuring syntax, and, as with usual destructuring, compjure's destructuring also allows mixing the destructuring and still getting the entire request:

```
(POST "/" [param1 param2 :as request]
        (str (:form-params request)))
```

or, extracting named and all "additional" parameters:

```
(POST "/" [param1 param2 & more-params]
        (str more-params))
```

Answer (score 4):

I just guessed to put `& params` in the vector and that worked:

```
(POST "/my-app" [& params]
  (str "<h1>Hello " params "</h1>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this return all the params:

```
(POST "/test" {params :params} 
    (str "POST params=" params))
```

use this notation to access a particular parameter:

```
(println (params :Nom))
```